Enbbeded SQL - Casting error on AS400
I am trying to get all the SQL column name and write to IFS file. This is done on IBMi systems. Here is the SQL statement
BEGIN                                                   
  DECLARE Cols VARCHAR(100);                            
                                                        
  Select LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',       ')               
    within group (Order By ORDINAL_POSITION) as cols    
    INTO Cols                                           
    From QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS                               
    Where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'VA967' AND                    
    TABLE_NAME = 'NETST';                               
                                                        
  CALL QSYS2.IFS_WRITE('/va967/NET_Job.txt', Cols, 'I');
END; 

I ran this statement using the following command
RUNSQLSTM SRCFILE(VA967/QCLLESRC) SRCMBR(A4) COMMIT(*NONE)
I am getting the following error - SQL0420  30       1  Position 1 Value for cast argument not valid.
Any help sould be appriciated.. Thanks

Please tag the database you are using

I found the error.. The call command should use named parameters.
CALL QSYS2.IFS_WRITE(               
      PATH_NAME => '/va967/NET_Job.txt',
      LINE => column_names,                     
      OVERWRITE => 'REPLACE',           
      END_OF_LINE => 'CRLF' );


